# LuaLaTeX Problem with Greek language

Tags: luatex, babel, greek

I'm trying to typeset this code with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Gentium Plus}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
Α α Α α
Β β  Β β
Γ γ  Γ γ
Δ δ  Δ δ
Ε ε  Ε ε
Ζ ζ  Ζ ζ
Η η  Η η
Θ θ  Θ θ
Ι ι  Ι ι
Κ κ  Κ κ
Λ λ  Λ λ
Μ μ  Μ μ
Ν ν  Ν ν
Ξ ξ  Ξ ξ
Ο ο  Ο ο
Π π  Π π
Ρ ρ  Ρ ρ
Σ σ  Σ σ
Τ τ  Τ τ
Υ υ  Υ υ
Φ φ  Φ φ
Χ χ  Χ χ
Ψ ψ  Ψ ψ
Ω ω  Ω ω
\end{document}
```

However, I get this warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

and an empty page (except for the page number at the bottom). (I'm using Gentium Plus here, but other fonts I've tested give me the same error.)

If I comment out the second line from above (`\usepackage[greek]{babel}`) everything works fine.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

(I'm using LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) on MacTeX 2016.)

Comment: Does it work with polyglossia?
`\usepackage{polyglossia}` and `\setmainlanguage{greek}`

Comment: I don't think that `babel-greek` supports LuaLaTeX (yet).

Comment: @MaxNoe Yes, it works. But I thought I shouldn't use `polyglossia` with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg OK. However, isn't the `test-unicode-greek.tex` file (from `babel-greek`) supposed to be compiled with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: polyglossia was designed for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Why do you think you should not use it?

Comment: My understanding was that I should use polyglossia with XeLaTeX and babel with LaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Am I wrong?

Comment: Polyglossia is also for lualatex and I use it exclusively since at least three years (for german and english, not greek).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine if you load fontspec before babel. The greek module checks the active font encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Gentium Plus}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
Α α Α α
Β β  Β β
Γ γ  Γ γ
Δ δ  Δ δ
Ε ε  Ε ε
Ζ ζ  Ζ ζ
Η η  Η η
Θ θ  Θ θ
Ι ι  Ι ι
Κ κ  Κ κ
Λ λ  Λ λ
Μ μ  Μ μ
Ν ν  Ν ν
Ξ ξ  Ξ ξ
Ο ο  Ο ο
Π π  Π π
Ρ ρ  Ρ ρ
Σ σ  Σ σ
Τ τ  Τ τ
Υ υ  Υ υ
Φ φ  Φ φ
Χ χ  Χ χ
Ψ ψ  Ψ ψ
Ω ω  Ω ω
\end{document}
```

[image]